# bootstrap 4 create modal footer with multiple rows

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm attempting to get a modal footer in bootstrap 4 to have multiple 100% width rows.  So for the most basic bootstrap modal example below, is it possible to get the Close and Save changes buttons to be on different rows and both be 100% width?

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div><div class="modal-body">
            ...
          </div><div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes for sure you can place two `modal-footer` elements.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button col-lg-12" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button col-lg-12" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then in your css add this

```
#exampleModalLong .modal-footer .btn {
  width:100%;
}
```

Here you have a jsfiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/tnw586h4/12/)

Comment: Thanks!  That's a really simple solution for how much time I just spent on that haha.

Comment: @ShaunPoore that's why is stackoverflow here :)

Comment: And it seems that this is the way to go if you want additional content in the `modal-header` section as well -- to add a second `div.modal-header` under the first one; though I would prefer a simple way to add content to a single modal header.

Answer (score 4):

A more "natural" way to do it would be to add

```
.modal-footer {
  display: block;
}
```

It's the default `display: flex` that makes the buttons share the same row.

Answer (score 0):

Having two times a `modal-footer` will result in two borders too.

Remove can be easily done with `border-0`:

```html
<div class="modal-footer">
    ...
</div>
<div class="modal-footer border-0">
    ...
</div>
```